# Thread was being aborted. @ System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)

Tags: c#

I have a windows service that works perfectly fine on multiple machines, but in this particular instance, I am getting this error.

```
at System.IO.FileStream.ReadFileNative(SafeFileHandle handle, Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 count, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, Int32& hr)
at System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
at mycoolclass.Access.FileSystemAccess.GetFileBytes(String filePath)
at mycoolerclass.GetValidPicturesAndStatistics(PicturesAndStatisticsInfo info)
```

Any Ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Would be nice to share the code that throws the exception and exception details as well (message, etc.)

Comment: Because the thread was being aborted, I'd wager. :P You might be calling `Thread.Abort` yourself, or rhe code might be hosted by an ASP.NET site that has requests being aborted, or some anti-malware program is going haywire, or (less probable but possible) a thread pool thread is mistakenly being aborted by code in the runtime (which would mean upgrading your version of .NET, most likely). Without context it's impossible to tell.

Comment: It's a windows service.